How to run chrome devtools natively as a standalone Android app like kiwi
For one of my projects, I needed to run chrome devtools on Android. From devtools-frontend setup docs, I successfully build the devtools-frontend into out/Default.
In that directory there are a few html files- devtools_app, js_app, node_app, inspector.
I don't know which one is the actual devtools, but devtools_app & inspector look somewhat close.
But neither in devtools_app nor in inspector, I can get the elements panel to load. It is always empty & throughout the world I cannot get any docs for how to connect it to a real page.
I thought that url bar in inspector would open the given url in devtools, but nothing happens in writing anything to it.
Also I cannot execute any js in Console panel. There is no error, no warning nothing. Pressing enter just gets rid of the written code & nothing is run.
So what am I missing? How to connect that devtools to a real webpage & how to get the console panel working?
I tried to inspect the devtools WebView in kiwi (which allows to run chrome devtools natively on Android). But surprisingly the devtools that opens in kiwi on inspecting any page is always the same link!!!
What???
devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@9c25b0453847af990895e9f681a4710784e34245/&targetType=tab
How does it load the webpage??? How can I load the webpage into my devtools?
What the hell is going on??
